# Unable to load a specific .dll (nmath dll) after publishing a vsto project ( .NET framework 4.8)

Tags: dll, frameworks, vsto, project, publish

It's my first time asking on stackoverflow.
So I have this VSTO excel addin project that targets .NETFramework 4.8 and which references a few net standard 2.0 in-house libraries. One of the library uses nmath to make some pricing.
The project works very well in debug mode, I launch the excel, the Add-in is there and no error while running all the functions but after publishing I get this error when running one of the function :

Unable to load DLL 'nmath_native_x64.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
at CenterSpace.NMath.Core.DotNetBlas.dcopy(Int32* n, Double* dx, Int32* xStride, Double* dy, Int32* yStride)

So to summary it seems that either it doens't get the right version of nmath after publishing or it just doesn't load the dll.

I have tried many things like multi-targeting frameworks, removing all warnings etc etc but nothing seems to work at the moment.

Comment: Is the native DLL you are talking about included in the installer, i.e. maybe it's actually missing? I don't think native DLLs are included automatically

Comment: Hello Nikolay, you were right thank you so much ! native dlls are not included automatically and I had to add a ref with a path in the app.config. Btw, If I want to deploy the application how can I make the path generic ? so let's say I'm adding the native lib in a folder in the publish folder, how can I find the path of the publish folder in any laptop ?

Comment: I think this may be a pretty wide topic for one question, try searching by something like "how do I include a third-party dlls in a VSTO project".

Comment: Thks Nicolay, It works when I specify the local path so it's already a first nice step ! however, any suggestion to make the path more generic ? instead of having something like "C:/users/debron/project/publish/x64Native" something like "../publish/x64Native" ? so it could find the path on any local computer as long as the publish folder contains x64Native ?